# Grand total does not always match the original PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

Has anyone experienced occasional increases in the grand total conformation from the shopping cart processed through PayPal Express Checkout?  It's not happening that often but it is an issue.

We have a new Magento Site version 1.9.1.0 using PayPal express checkout.  The site has been up now for over a month with over 100 successful Paypal transactions so everything seems to be working 99%.

The problem is we have received about 6 calls where the customer is telling us that the checkout amount was correct and even when they went to PayPal it also was correct.  However, when they returned back to the grand total on the site to confirm that amount had been increased. No precise amount to pinpoint double shipping or anything else. It seems to be a random issue on different browsers.

Today the example was a $95.90 order with $25.10 shipping for a total of $121. All was fine until the customer returned to confirm and the price jumped $18.86.  She called and we asked if she would continue with the transaction as another customer had the same issue and the PayPal amount charged was correct. She graciously did and the PayPal charge did come out to the correct $121.

We have checked with PayPal and they know of no issues with Magento. It's an issue for us as it appears that we are slipping in extra charges.  We also don't know of how many PayPal transactions were aborted at this point with a lost sale based on trusting us.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical Express Checkout / Magento integration, shipping and/or tax is added on the order review page, where customer is returned after they log into PayPal to authorize the purchase. This page is also where shipping charges are applied "typically", because the cart doesn't have the customer shipping address from PayPal until it is applied here.

Any number the customer sees before this point should be a subtotal.

If you have Magento set up to collect the customer shipping address and apply the shipping charge BEFORE the customer arrives at the PayPal login page, my guess is there is a conflict because shipping is being applied twice, at least temporarily, and in the end Magento appears to be applying the shipping charge based upon the information typed into the form.

The discrepancy in the amounts could possibly be attributed to a subtle difference between what PayPal has on file and sends to the cart, and what the customer typed into your form.

Lastly, this is a POSSIBLE solution; I know very little about your configuration so I can only give an educated guess as to that is actually happening. It's worth testing though.